# Javascript comparing variables

Tags: javascript

Hey I am making simple game and getting some functions done but i am not sure what i am doing here wrong. It always alerts "Incorrect" I have made a text box and a button. when button is pressed it calls getAnswer() and compares the variable with whatever was in the textbox. I have feeling i am doing something wrong with assigning the variable textBox. But not sure.

```
var currentWord = "hi"


function getAnswer(){
var textBox = document.getElementById('answer_box');
if (textBox == currentWord){
alert("Correct!");
}else{
alert("Incorrect!");
}
```

the button and text box code

```
<input type="text" id="answer_box"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getAnswer();" />
```

Comment: debugging 101: `console.log(textbox,currentWord);` That would show you in the console why it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the **value** of the textbox with your variable, not the textbox itself!

`var textBox = document.getElementById('answer_box').value;`

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare the value of the text box not the element itself:

```
textBox == currentWord
```

should be

```
textBox.value == currentWord
```

Comment: @thg435, would be even more correct if you used `===` instead of `==`  ;)  There are a few answers that are just as "correct" as yours!

Comment: @DerekHenderson - I agree that there are others here that are just as correct as mine.  I wouldn't assume that === should be used, what if the requirement was for "1" to be equal to 1 in this case?

Comment: @JustinBicknell, you can check the truthiness of that comparison without coercing the type of either value.  I can't really think of any instances when type coercion like this is a good idea.  (But this probably isn't the best place to discuss this, as it's not really relevant to the answer.  I was just needling the "This is the correct one" declaration when there are several answers that are just as correct.)

Comment: @DerekHenderson: in case you're wondering, I liked this answer because of the correct use of names. `textBox.value == something` is correct, `var textBox = something.value` is not - you cannot assign a "value" to a variable named "textBox".

Comment: @DerekHenderson - I agree that this isn't the forum for that discussion, as it comes down to a business decision.  Also, I didn't want to assume or adjust the original code to make it behave in a different manner than what it was originally doing (apart from correcting the problem)

Comment: @thg435, I understood why you liked it, and semantically you are correct.  But semantic correctness and syntactic correctness are two entirely different beasts. If 'Box' happened to mean 'value' in some obscure language or dialect, then the semantic meaning changes.  If the variable is renamed 'textboxValue', again the semantic meaning changes. But in terms of correct JS syntax, either approach is correct.  The question was, after all, about comparing variable values, not semantic variable naming conventions.

Comment: @JustinBicknell About `===` vs. `==`. When getting the value with `.value`, the result is always a string. So it's safe to use `=== "some string"` (where "some string" is `currentWord`) since the `.value` will be a string. In other situations, if you want to compare 2 values and aren't sure of the types, they should be converted first anyways

Comment: @Ian - I understand that .value gives a string, but what you are comparing that to "currentWord" may be anything, albeit the case above it is a string but assuming that could change.

Comment: @JustinBicknell Right, but it's a string right now. So yes, if that changes to not be a string, which I'm not sure why it would, then you couldn't use `===`. But like I said, if they are meant to be numbers, they should be converted to numbers first. If they are meant to be strings, they can be converted to strings (if the input types aren't known, or unknown ones only)

Comment: @Ian - yes you should definitely do proper type conversion when capturing user input, which is beyond the scope of this question.  Again, if this question had to do with type conversion and such, than using === would have been essential

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the value from the text box. Try:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById('answer_box').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use textbox.value in the comparison!

Answer (score 0):

your textBox contains the DOM element and not the value, you need to get the value with .value;

so you need

```
if (textBox.value === currentWord)
```